# Adding data to options table

Tags: options

I am currently tweaking a plugin so that all "contributors" (here referred to as "players") are automatically subscribed to a forum. I basically want to subscribe everyone with the role of contributor and above (I've used user_level because the rest of the plugin does and I thought I should be consistent.)

```
function forum_subscribe_member_player()
{
    $players= get_users();

    foreach($players as $player){

        $playeremail = get_userdata($player->ID, 'user_email');
        if(!empty($playeremail) && $player->user_level >= 1)
        {                   
            $list = get_option("mf_forum_subscribers_1", array());


            if( is_player_subscribed($player->ID)) //remove user if already exists (user clicked unsubscribe)
            {
                $key = array_search($playeremail, $list);
                unset($list[$key]);
            }
            else
                $list[] = $playeremail;
            update_option("mf_forum_subscribers_1", $list);
        }
    }       
}
```

Its not working and I'm guessing there is a problem with `$player->is_player_subscribed()` which is here :

```
 function is_player_subscribed($user_ID)
{
      if($user_ID)
      {
        $useremail = get_userdata($user_ID, 'user_email');
        $list = get_option("mf_forum_subscribers_1", array());
        if(in_array($useremail, $list)){
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
}
```

Which uses the `global $user_ID` rather than `get_users()` I would love some help with this or even to be pointed in the right direction.

EDIT: based on comment by @murdaugh

Comment: `$player->is_forum_subscribed()` would imply that `is_forum_subscribed()` is a public function (method) of the WP_User class. It's not. My recommendation would be to refactor that function to accept a user_id (forget about the global) and use that parameter to do your lookup/get_option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an expansion of my comment on OP:

```
function is_forum_subscribed($user_ID) {
  if($user_ID)
  {
    $useremail = $this->get_userdata($user_ID, 'user_email');
    $list = get_option("mf_forum_subscribers_".$this->current_forum, array());
    if(in_array($useremail, $list))
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

You can call this function like this, instead:

```
is_forum_subscribed($player->ID);
```

Comment: Thanks @murdaugh I created two separate functions instead, as the other two originally dealt with the current user and I want a function that runs on init and covers all users to whom it applies. I'm having trouble calling it or hooking into it though. I tried `add_action( 'init', "forum_subscribe_member_player" ) but perhaps I'm calling it in the wrong place.

Comment: If `init` is too early, you might try calling it in `wp_loaded` but it's hard to know without seeing all the resources you're trying to utilize.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Its all contained in a class that does have an init function but everything refers to the class (using $this). Would it make more sense to include it in functions.php since it deals only with the options table and doesn't refer to anything in the class(that I can see?) Or is that a bad idea?

Comment: If you can, toss that entire class (with your is_forum_subscribed() function) in a gist. It would be a lot easier to understand what is happening that way.

Comment: I actually decided it belonged in functions.php (or perhaps I was just being lazy) but I still need to figure out how to exclude those who have clicked unsubscribe `if($this->is_forum_subscribed())` but that may be another question. Here's th gist in case you're curious: https://gist.github.com/mantismamita/6845919 Thanks for your help.